How do I derive the inverse of the function $f(x) = \frac{e^x -1}{x}$.
I'm trying to rearrange the function to isolate $x$, but I'm not sure what the first step is.
$f(x) = \frac{e^x -1}{x}$
I suspect the Lambert W function crops up somewhere.

Mathematica:
$$\frac{-1 -W(-\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x}) x}{x}$$
where $W$ is the product log function.

That’s a pretty good hint for the OP to start with.

"Hint"?  It is the answer!

Nein, the question was how to derive it.
